# Convert TIFF to PostScript

Tags: .net, tiff, postscript, cmyk

I'm writing .net code (Windows Forms Application) which reads a TIFF image (CMYK) and sends it to printer (using WritePrinter). Before I send it, I need to convert the TIFF image to PostScript. Could any of you share the code how to create PostScript out of TIFF image? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My company's product, [dotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/DotImage/) includes an encode for EPS, but it will also generate page generation operators.

Typical usage might be something like this:

```
public void ConvertToPS(Stram tiffStm, int frame, Stream psStm) {
    using (AtalaImage image = new AtalaImage(tiffStm, frame, null)) {
        EpsEncoder encoder = new EpsEncoder();
        encoder.IncludeShowPage = true;
        encoder.Save(image, psStm, null);
    }
}
```

If you need to do batch conversions, we have resource management to make that easy too (ie, loop over an entire set of (possibly multipage) TIFFs).  Also, this encoder will honor color profiles in the images and handles the following image formats:

- 1 bit per pixel, black and white
- 8 bit per pixel gray
- 24 bit per pixel RGB
- 32 bit per pixel CMYK

It will scale the image, if desired, invert black and white images, apply resolution transforms, apply PostScript document structuring conventions, etc.

Give it a try - we have a free trial.  Let me know (or call our support line) if you don't see something you need.

Answer (score 0):

If using an external library/tool is an option: the standard and reference *libtiff* implementation ships with more than a dozen commandline utilities. 2 of those are **tiff2ps** and **tiff2pdf**. See also http://www.libtiff.org/tools.html

Answer (score -2):

You could use an external app to do this job for you, like this one: http://pt.softpicks.net/software/Multimedia/Convertores-e-Otimizadores/PS-to-Tiff-command-line_pt-52736.htm

All you should do is follow this script:

1. Store your TIFF image as a temporary file
2. Execute this app to make the conversion
3. Return this converted file to your printer.

Comment: Ops: ignore the link. This application convert PS to Tiff. But you could search for some other alternative which could do this job for you.