# Convert TIFF image file to .ps using C#/VB.net

Tags: .net, postscript

I need to find a way of converting TIFF image files to .ps files using C#/VB.NET. I treid using MODI (Microsoft Office Document Imaging) to generate .ps file, If I open a .ps file with word pad or any other editor I should be able to read this file. I tried to open the .PS file and its opening with some Characters which means it's an image file.

Are there any free methods or APIs to convert tiff to .ps?

Thanks
Sathish

Comment: Looks like there is a duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848787/convert-tiff-to-postscript

Answer (score 1):

<del>Use [ghostscript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/) from a command line (`Process.Start()`).</del>

Ghostscript is for pdf -> tiff.

Use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for TIFF to PDF conversions:

```
convert yourtiff.tif -density 72 yourpdf.pdf
```

Comment: You are correct. I use ghostscript for pdf -> tiff conversions and ImageMagick for tif -> pdf conversions. I've updated my answer since I obviously mixed them up.